# How can i set loop iMacros by Javascript?

Tags: javascript, imacros

1) I can't add set loop imacros by javascript, How can i add it ?

```
var macro;
    macro =  "CODE:";
    macro +=  "VERSION BUILD=8011895" + "\n"; 
    macro +=  "TAB T=1" + "\n"; 
    macro +=  "SET !ERRORIGNORE YES" + "\n"; 
    macro +=  "SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO" + "\n"; 
    macro +=  "SET !TIMEOUT 3" + "\n"; 
    macro +=  "SET !EXTRACT NULL" + "\n"; 
    //macro +=  "SET !LOOP 1" + "\n"; 
    macro +=  "TAG POS={{loop}} TYPE=A ATTR=CLASS:twitter-timeline-link EXTRACT=TXT" + "\n"; 
    macro +=  "SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=* FILE=twitter.csv" + "\n"; 
    var extractedtext=iimGetLastExtract();
    iimPlay(macro);
```

2) How can i use that code on imacros without javascript ? ( on iim)

```
var extractedtext=iimGetLastExtract();
```

Answer (score 3):

Specify your imacros code as a javscript string and prefix with **CODE:**

```
var urls = ['http://google.com', 'http://yahoo.com'];

for (var i in urls) {
  var url = urls[i];
  var returnCode = iimPlay('CODE: URL GOTO='+url);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to write macro like this

```
var macro;

macro ="CODE:";
macro +="TAG POS={{i}} TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TITLE:link"+"\n";

///The triggering part

for (var i=1;i<10;i++)
{

iimSet("i",i)
iimPlay(macro)
}
```

Since you example was kind of unclear I have to say that this command might not work.

```
TAG POS={{i}} TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TITLE:link
```

Instead of word link replace it with * which means any character and then it can work

```
TAG POS={{i}} TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TITLE:*
```

Also in the macro you can write like this

```
TAG POS={{variable}} TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TITLE:*
```

But in the iimSet part it has be like this.

```
iimSet("variable",i)
```

Answer (score 1):

1) to loop javascript code you can add `for` statement like this:

```
for (i=1;i<=n;i++){
iimPlay(macro);
}
```

where n is number of loops to perform

2) in iim you do not need it as `!extract` parameter already has extracted value

Answer (score 0):

I understand how to make imacros for firefox loop using javascript, but the question is how does the variable carry over into the called macro here:

```
iimPlay(macro);
```

the first time let's say you want to click on link pos=1

then 2nd time on link pos=2

if your called iim script is:

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TITLE:link
```

how will the script know how to look at position 2 (POS=2) the next time and POS=3 the subsquent time?

is it correct to type the following?

```
TAG POS=i TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TITLE:link
```