# Stuck on 1st line of .csv file

Tags: javascript, loops, csv

First, my question is similar to this one, but this answer did not work for me:
[How can i set loop iMacros by Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14147290/how-can-i-set-loop-imacros-by-javascript)

It's a 3 part code that uses 2 different datasourse .csv files.  The first loop works fine, but the second time around it does not go to line 2 of the .csv files, it just keeps reinserting the same info from line 1.

I think it somehow is resetting the variable each time it loops, instead of going up by 1 it is just repeating 1, 1, 1, etc.

I need someway for the  "loop" variable to go up by 1 each time around.  I already tried changing "loop" to "i".

Here is the code:

```
var jsLF = "\n";
var i;

var macro;
macro = "CODE:";
macro +=  "SET !ERRORIGNORE YES" + "\n"; 
macro +=  "SET !ERRORCONTINUE YES" + "\n"; 
macro +=  "CMDLINE !DATASOURCE PINaccounts.csv" + "\n"; 
macro +=  "SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 9" + "\n"; 
macro +=  "SET !loop 1" + "\n"; 
macro +=  "SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!loop}}" + "\n"; 
macro +=  "TAB T=1" + "\n"; 
macro +=  "URL GOTO=http://pinterest.com/" + "\n"; 
macro +=  "TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=CLASS:profileImage&&TXT:" + "\n"; 
macro +=  "TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Log<SP>Out" + "\n"; 
macro +=  "TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Log<SP>in<SP>now" + "\n"; 
macro +=  "TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:EMAIL FORM=NAME:NoFormName ATTR=NAME:username_or_email CONTENT={{!COL3}}" + "\n"; 
macro +=  "SET !ENCRYPTION NO" + "\n"; 
macro +=  "TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:PASSWORD FORM=NAME:NoFormName ATTR=NAME:password CONTENT={{!COL4}}" + "\n"; 
macro +=  "TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON FORM=NAME:NoFormName ATTR=TXT:Log<SP>in" + "\n"; 
macro +=  "wait seconds=2" + "\n"; 

var change;
change = "CODE:";
change +=  "CMDLINE !DATASOURCE PINfollowers.csv" + "\n"; 
change +=  "SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 1" + "\n"; 
change +=  "SET !loop 1" + "\n"; 
change +=  "SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!loop}}" + "\n"; 
change +=  "TAB T=1" + "\n"; 
change +=  "URL GOTO={{!COL1}}" + "\n"; 

var fol;
fol = "CODE:";
fol +=  "SET !ERRORIGNORE YES" + "\n"; 
fol +=  "SET !ERRORCONTINUE YES" + "\n"; 
fol +=  "TAB T=1" + "\n"; 
fol +=  "TAG POS={{!loop}} TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TXT:Follow" + "\n"; 
fol +=  "WAIT SECONDS=2" + "\n"; 


/* ----------------------- Login loop 6 times ------------------------------ */
for (i = 1; i <= 6; i++)
   {
   iimSet("loop", i);
   iimPlay(macro);
   iimPlay(change);


/* ----------------------- Follow loop 180 times for each Login ----------------------------- */
    for (i = 1; i <= 180; i++)
    {
     iimSet("loop", i);
     iimPlay(fol);
     }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using the same counter for each loop.

Try keeping `i` for the outer loop, and use `j` for the inner loop.

```
for (i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
    iimSet("loop", i);
    iimPlay(macro);
    iimPlay(change);

    for (j = 1; j <= 180; j++) {
        iimSet("loop", j);
        iimPlay(fol);
    }
}
```

Comment: I just tried that and it didn't seem to work.  It kept inputting the data from only Row 1.         I'm pretty sure it has to do with these lines:                                                              macro +=  "SET !loop 1" + "\n"; 
macro +=  "SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!loop}}" + \n";                                                                                                                                        It's resetting back to 1 every time through.  I need to use a variable from outside of the imacro i think.

Comment: I even tried    "SET !loop i"    but the code didn't work since i was putting a javascript variable into an iMacro code.      i somehow need to separate the two.

Comment: do i have to add   ret=iimSet("i",i);    ?  then change the word "loop" to "i"?

Comment: I need to somehow insert a javascript variable, "i", into the middle of the iMacro code.        But since i cannot insert "i" it keeps going back to 1 every time the loop starts each time.

Answer (score 0):

So does anyone know how i can insert the javascript variable "i" into the middle of the iMacro script?  The code below didn't work.

```
macro +=  "SET i" + "\n"; 
macro +=  "SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{i}}" + "\n";
```